# Website Responsiveness Issue on iPhones with Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, bootstrap-5

I am facing an issue with the responsiveness of a website I am working on, specifically on iPhones. The website is built using Bootstrap 5 and appears to be functioning correctly on Android phones as well as in Chrome Dev Tools. However, when I test it on iPhones, certain elements do not display properly.

To provide a visual representation of the problem, please find below a couple of screenshots illustrating the issue:

| Android | iPhone |
| --- | --- |
| [image: On Android] | [image: On IPhone] |

The issue seems to be related to how the website's layout and components are rendered on iPhones. The elements do not align correctly, and the overall layout appears distorted. This behavior is not observed on Android devices or when using Chrome Dev Tools to simulate different mobile devices.

If you want to see the website by yourself this is the page: https://sbriser.com/universo/personaggi/Sbriser

I have already tried some troubleshooting steps like the following:

Ensured that I am using the viewport meta tag in the HTML <head> section:

html

Despite these attempts, the responsiveness issue persists on iPhones. I suspect there might be some CSS conflict or specific iPhone-related styling that I am overlooking.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has expertise in Bootstrap 5 and responsive web design, I would greatly appreciate your guidance and assistance. Are there any additional CSS rules or JavaScript tweaks that could help ensure proper responsiveness on iPhones?

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

Comment: I [validated your HTML code](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fsbriser.com%2Funiverso%2Fpersonaggi%2FSbriser) and it seems your HTML tags are not balanced. Safari might be sensitive to this. Balance the tags, and perhaps it will work?

Comment: Thank you so much. Since this website it's not made by me and it's generated by php I had not noticed the tag unbalance

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persitsts

Comment: Well, it was worth a try, and you don't want to have unbalanced tags. Next thing you could try is to use the [Debug Console or Web Inspector](https://www.lifewire.com/activate-the-debug-console-in-safari-445798), they might give you more information about what's wrong. Note that you need both an iOS and MacOS device to use this. I've got an iOS device but no MacOS device, so I have no access to this debugging tool.

Comment: I also don't have any Apple device, I'm using an emulator to do the tests

Comment: I found the solution! There were some wrong CSS lines that are simply ignored by chromium based browsers but not by safari

Comment: That's nice. You can contribute to the Stack Overflow community by providing this, and it's details, as an answer to your own question. I will upvote it if you do.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a lot on a website that wasn't mine I found that the HTML tags weren't balanced, but that wasn't the main error. I found some wrong CSS lines that are simply ignored by chromium based browsers but not by safari.

The problem was that in a .row element (I don't know why those lines were there) there were the following lines:

```css
.row {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-warp: wrap;
}
```